# How to queue a kernel apc

Tags: driver, apc, kernel-mode

Just want to understand APCs better. To queue a user mode APC, we can use the [QueueUserAPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function. So how to queue a special/normal kernel mode APC? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

APC must be allocated only from non-paged pool because APC can be inserted (by *KeInsertQueueAPC*) in thread list at *DPC* level - so if you for example allocate *KAPC* from paged pool, insert it, and then somebody try insert another *APC* at *DPC* level - your paged *APC* data can be assigned (when inserted to linked list) and as result *BSOD*

for initialize *KAPC* use *KeInitializeApc*. if for free *APC* need exactly call *ExFreePool* and nothing more you can use 0 as *RundownRoutine*. otherwise you must provide own *RundownRoutine* for correct cleanup. *KernelRoutine* always must be set, and because almost always it point to some function in your driver - driver must not be unloaded until *APC* will be not executed. usual need call *ObfReferenceObject* for driver object before insert *APC* by *KeInsertQueueAPC* and *ObfDereferenceObject* after *KernelRoutine* or *RundownRoutine* will be executed (or *KeInsertQueueAPC* return false). but you can not "normal way" call *ObfDereferenceObject* - this is senseless (if driver hold on last reference - will be crash when *ObfDereferenceObject* return to your driver code. you need assembly written proxy from *KernelRoutine* and *RundownRoutine* which call they c/c++ implementation and on exit do *jmp* (but not *call* !!) instruction to *ObfDereferenceObject* and stack must be special rebuild for after *ObfDereferenceObject* call *ret* - code will be returned to kernel code, which call your driver callback routine (kernel or rundown) - so skip driver code execute after *ObfDereferenceObject*

for more details - read [Inside NT's Asynchronous Procedure Call](http://www.drdobbs.com/inside-nts-asynchronous-procedure-call/184416590) - despite this is already very old article - nothing changed from this time and in latest win 10 - all the same